# Understanding int() and mod() functions as used in this formula

Tags: notation

**Context:** SCOM metric to measure software class cohesion

**Paper:** [A SENSITIVE METRIC OF CLASS COHESION](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=55D08270F99333F15E0937AF137F4468?doi=10.1.1.84.1506&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Luis Fernández and Rosalía Peña.

The equation in question is on page 86:

$S(m,a) = \frac 12[1 + int(\frac {m-1}a)][mod(\frac {m-1}a) + m -1]$

Where `m` is the number of methods of a class and `a` is the number of attributes of the class.

I believe the `int()` function used here is the [Integer Part function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerPart.html). **But what is the meaning of the `mod()` function?** I can't find a reference to the modulus function where it takes just one argument therefore I can't say for sure that that's what it means.

Comment: It's most likely referring to $m-1 \bmod{a}$.

Comment: Maybe is the *reminder*; see [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By comparing with the line immediately above it in the paper, and assuming the authors didn't make a typo, it must be the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part), which is sometimes considered as "modulo 1". I suppose for these authors, the second argument of "mod" can be dropped when it is 1.